# What is the total area enclosed between the curve $y=x^2-1$, the x-axis and the lines $x=-2$ and $x=2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

> What is the total area enclosed between the curve $y=x^2-1$, the x-axis and the lines $x=-2$ and $x=2$?

I tried to find the area by using the integrals $\int_1^2$ and $\int_{-1}^{-2}$ .

$x^2-1$ integrated is $\frac{x^3}{3}-x$

The answer is supposed to be $4$, but by adding up  $\int_1^2$ and $\int_{-1}^{-2}$  my area is $\frac{8}{3}$.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the area *under* the x-axis. The signed area of this is:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x^2-1 \ dx \ $$

Can you continue?

Comment: Thanks! I calculated the area under the x-axis. It gives me the area $\frac{-4}{3}$. Do I add it to the other areas even though it's negative?

Comment: If $-1 < x < 1$, then $x^2 - 1 < 0$.

Comment: No, since areas cannot be negative (in this case). You should add the *absolute value* of all the areas since this will always give a positive answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now the area is 4.

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, it is twice the area between the $y$-axis and the line $x=2$. The positive $x$-intercept is $x=1$, and on the interval $[0,1]$, the curve is below the $x$-axis, hence the total (geometric) area is
$$2\biggl(\int_1^2y(x)\,\mathrm d x-\int_0^1y(x)\,\mathrm d x\biggl).$$

Answer (score 1):

It is an even function Required Area will be , $$ Area = 2\;(\int_0^2| x^2\;-1| \,dx)$$ $$=2(\;\int_0^1(1-x^2)\,dx\;+\int_1^2(x^2-1)\,dx\;)$$$$=2( \, \frac23\;+\;\frac43\,)=\;4 $$